# Web.API Security for mobile calls

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api

I am new at this and can't find a clear solution, so any help in the right direction would help me a lot!

I have an MVC 4 Web Application that uses Form Authentication - uses a custom Users table - none of that Identity stuff.

Now there's the need to add a series of Web API controllers to be consumed by a mobile application.

How do I take care of the security part, so each particular user can access its own particular data?

Comment: How are you planning to authenticate your users in the mobile application?

Comment: I have no clue, i will not be doing the mobile part. It will have to use my Users table - shouldn't really matter, right?.  I imagine some sort of token related authentication..